# Spring check if there is no param

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm building a search engine in Spring and at the moment I can query results from the database. My URL is like

> www.myurl.com/jobs=?test

I made an "if" statement to check if the object is empty it must return a message that there is nothing found in the database. However, when I go to the

> www.myurl.com/jobs

I also get the same message.

Is there a way to fix this so I don't get that message? I need to check if there is no parameter - then it should return or do something else.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@RequestParam(value="search", required=false) String result, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("results", jobsDao.getQueryresult(result));
    return "result";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle this, depending on how the rest of your code looks.

Arguably the cleanest approach would be to use an `Optional` to differentiate between each case:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@RequestParam(value="search") Optional<String> query, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("results", jobsDao.getQueryresult(query));
    if (query.isPresent()) {
        return "results";
    } else {
        return "jobs-index";
    }
}
```

If you cannot use Java 8's `Optional` you can create two controller methods and narrow down the mappings using the `param` qualifier:

```
// this will only get triggered if the URL contains the "search" parameter
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="search")
public String search(@RequestParam(value="search") String query, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("results", jobsDao.getQueryresult(query));
    return "results";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String search() {
    return "jobs-index";
}
```